# Availability of SharedPreferences to multiuser-aware android apps

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Consider an android application is not a [singleton](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multiuser-apps) (android:singleUser=”false”) and it has stored a few shared preferences with `MODE_PRIVATE` under a particular user. When the user switch happens on the device, will the shared preferences being stored as part of the other user be unavailable to the application as the current user is different now?

Comment: Well is it difficult to try and find out?